Pure SQL from postgres to django
We have a pure SQL in postgres that groups the instance visits registered in that table grouped by country, what I need is to pass this pure query to django queryset to get the same result
Here is the pure SQL query:
SELECT
        country,
        SUM(difference) AS total_difference
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            entry_or_exit_datetime AS entry_time,
            LEAD(entry_or_exit_datetime) OVER (ORDER BY entry_or_exit_datetime) AS exit_time,
            EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (LEAD(entry_or_exit_datetime) OVER (ORDER BY entry_or_exit_datetime) - entry_or_exit_datetime)) AS difference,
            country
        FROM (
            SELECT
                id,
                entry_or_exit_datetime,
                country,
                LAG(is_joining) OVER (ORDER BY entry_or_exit_datetime) AS prev_is_joining
            FROM
                public.access_sectionslog
            WHERE
                date(entry_or_exit_datetime) >= '2024-05-17'
                AND date(entry_or_exit_datetime) <= '2024-05-23'
                AND section_name = 'landing-page'
                AND country IN ('VE', 'CO')
        ) AS subquery
    ) AS subquery_with_difference
    GROUP BY country;

result:

This is the model in django:
class SectionsLog(BaseModel):

    class SectionNameChoice(models.TextChoices):
        GROUPS = "section-groups", _("Groups")
        FEED = "section-feed", _("Feed")
        NEWS = "section-news", _("News")
        LANDING_PAGE = "landing-page", _("Landing Page")
        EXTERNALS_SHARING = "external-sharing", _("External Sharing")
        LIVESCORE = "section-livescore", _("Livescore")
        SALES_PAGE = "sales-page", _("Sales page")
        ON_BOARDING = "onboarding", _("On boarding")

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="sections_log",
    )
    section_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=SectionNameChoice.choices,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    is_joining = models.BooleanField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Enter the Section(True)/Leave the Section(False)",
    )
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Is True to anybody who enter to the landing page without an user access token.",
    )
    entry_or_exit_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    user_ip = models.CharField(
        max_length=350,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    city = models.CharField(
        max_length=220,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=220,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    latitude = models.CharField(
        max_length=90,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    region = models.CharField(
        max_length=90,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    timezone = models.CharField(
        max_length=90,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        direction = "unknow"
        user = self.user

        if not self.user and self.is_anonymous:
            user = f"Anonymous User (IP:{self.user_ip})"

        if self.is_joining:
            direction = "enter"
        else:
            direction = "leave"
        return f"{user} {direction} {self.section_name} section"

I have tried to do it this way but it generates an error.
sportyeah_local_django  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
sportyeah_local_django  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
sportyeah_local_django  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
sportyeah_local_django  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
sportyeah_local_django  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sportyeah_local_django  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 723, in execute
sportyeah_local_django  |     raise ex.with_traceback(None)
sportyeah_local_django  | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: window function lead requires an OVER clause
sportyeah_local_django  | LINE 1: SELECT "access_sectionslog"."country", SUM((LEAD("access_sec...

The Code:
class SectionLogAnalyticsInstaceView(APIView):

    @extend_schema(
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter(
                "section_name",
                OpenApiTypes.STR,
                required=False,
                description="Ejemplo: external-sharing",
            ),
            OpenApiParameter(
                name="start_date",
                description="Fecha de inicio del rango de búsqueda (YYYY-MM-DD)",
                required=False,
                type=OpenApiTypes.DATE,
            ),
            OpenApiParameter(
                name="end_date",
                description="Fecha de fin del rango de búsqueda (YYYY-MM-DD)",
                required=False,
                type=OpenApiTypes.DATE,
            ),
            OpenApiParameter(
                "country",
                OpenApiTypes.STR,
                required=False,
                description="Ejemplo: ES o VE o tambien CO",
            ),
        ],
        tags=["analytics"],
    )
    def get(self, request):
    
        start_date = datetime.strptime('2024-05-17', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        end_date = datetime.strptime('2024-05-23', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        countries = ['VE', 'CO']
        # Calcular la duración de la estancia
        subquery = SectionsLog.objects.filter(
            entry_or_exit_datetime__date__range=(start_date, end_date),
            section_name=SectionsLog.SectionNameChoice.LANDING_PAGE,
            country__in=countries
        ).annotate(
            prev_is_joining=Window(
                expression=Lead('is_joining'),
                order_by=F('entry_or_exit_datetime').asc()
            )
        )

        subquery_with_difference = subquery.annotate(
            entry_time=F('entry_or_exit_datetime'),
            exit_time=Window(
                expression=Lead('entry_or_exit_datetime'),
                order_by=F('entry_or_exit_datetime').asc()
            ),
            difference=ExpressionWrapper(
                RawSQL("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (?? - ??))", ['exit_time', 'entry_time']),
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )

        # Define the final query
        final_query = subquery_with_difference.values('country').annotate(
            total_difference=Sum('difference')
        )


        return Response(final_query)


Add the full traceback.

Full code as indicated.

@vdjkelly by traceback he means complete error screenshot that comes

@willeM_VanOnsem sorry, error added

@vdjkelly Have you tried to execute the raw query with database cursor,as shown in this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

You can use .raw(<your SQL query here>) as it is always the answer for complex queries like these. In .raw(<your SQL query here>) you can input the direct SQL query as you have mentioned above. But remember that you have to change these SQL queries i.e. for MySQL or PostgreSQL etc. whenever you want to change DB in future in case you want to. On the other hand, The ORM query doesn't change even if the DB changes. More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/

The thing is, using raw would be my last option. I want to use the cleanest possible query. If you can help me, thank you.
